# Writing into same OpenXmlPart being read

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, xmlreader, xmlwriter

Is there a way write into the same `OpenXmlPart` that is being read by an `OpenXmlPartReader`? I'm going to detect things with the reader and potentially write things in place with an `OpenXmlWriter`. Here is a sample that does not work:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

MainDocumentPart part = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
part.Document = new Document(new Body(new Paragraph(), new Paragraph()));
doc.Save();

var stream = part.GetStream();
var reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(stream);
var writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(stream);

reader.Read(); // read w:document
reader.ReadFirstChild(); // read w:body
reader.ReadFirstChild(); // read 1st w:p
writer.WriteElement(new Table()); // try to insert w:tbl

doc.Save(); // observe only the 2 paragraphs in the `w:body`.
```

It looks like under the covers the Open XML SDK is using `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` under the covers, so perhaps there is a way to synchronize those?

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that there is no way to synchronize the `OpenXmlReader` and `OpenXmlWriter` out of the box.

What I ended up doing was cloning the original document, clearing out the parts and writing into them conditionally, while reading out of the `OpenXmlReader`.

Here is a simplified model of what I did:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var inputDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

MainDocumentPart inputMainPart = inputDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
inputMainPart.Document = new Document(new Body(new Paragraph(), new Paragraph()));
input.Save();

var outputDoc = input.Clone();
outputDoc.RemovePart(outputDoc.MainDocumentPart);
var outputMainPart = outputDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();


var reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(inputMainPart);
var writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(outputMainPart);
// write body/document

reader.Read(); // read w:document
reader.ReadFirstChild(); // read w:body
reader.ReadFirstChild(); // read 1st w:p

do {
    writer.WriteElement(new Table()); // insert w:tbl
    writer.WriteElement(reader.LoadCurrentElement());
} while(reader.ReadNextSibling());
doc.Save(); // observe only the 2 paragraphs in the `w:body`.
```